# Is a trinitarian-like view of God found in the Tanakh and held in Judaism?

Tags: tanach, theology, christianity

Is a triune quality to God's nature, like the Trinity as espoused in Christianity, a foreign teaching as far as Judaism is concerned? Or is such a belief held (or have been historically held) by Jews?

Comment: I don't know why my question is being voted down and to be closed. If the doctrine of the Trinity is not found in the Tanakh then it should be easily proven, and every Jew with a similar question could come here to have it answered. Closing this question would cause Jews to look for answers else where, perhaps from sources which believe there is a Trinity in the Tanakh.

Comment: Since the doctrine of multiple deities (such as Zoroastrianism - 2) or trinitarianism (3) are definitely not Judaism, they fall under that comparitive religion rubric.

Answer (score 3):

The Shema, a central verse in Judaism, states "Hear, O Israel, the Lord our God is One." So no.

Comment: Jews for J read that as alluding to the Trinity, so it's not much of a proof (according to them)

Comment: Christians do of course uphold this statement as true.

Comment: @robev you should ask them how they translate and interpret verses such as Gen 21:15, 22:2 and Isa 51:2 in which the Hebrew Echad (feminine Achad) is used...

Answer (score 2):

Besides the Shema mentioned in Deuteronomium 6:4.

Te following verses are important to gain some Understanding of G-d.

Exodus 20:3 “There shall not be to you other gods ‘al panai’.” The words al panai mean
“in addition to My presence” or “besides My presence” or “in My visible surface”, although the literal translation would be upon My face, or over My face; literally replacing the face (appearance) of G-d (i.e. the way He presents Himself to us) with another face or false representation of who He truly is.

Exodus 20:23 “you will not make for you gods with Me” - The Talmud derives further, based on a slightly different interpretation of that verse, that we may not produce an image of G-d Himself (“lo ta’asun oati” rather than “iti”). Nor may we turn to idols, or make any (see Exodus 20:4, 34:17, Leviticus 19:4 for  example).

Exodus 34:14 “You shall not bow down [in worship] before another god”

Deuteronomy 4:35 “You have obtained the insight, by the knowledge that He is HaShem, G-d, and there is none else; nothing but Him, there is nothing more than Him, none other than Him”.

And in Deuteronomy 4:39 it is written again: “You will know and let it (re)turn to the heart (take it to heart/turned [it] back unto thy heart), that He, HaShem, is G-d, above in the heavens and on the earth underneath, and none else”. *Ein od milvado.*

Deuteronomy 5:7, see Exodus 20:3.

Deuteronomy 6:14 “Do not follow/go after gods” which meaning is given “[made up] gods [and idols] of the people that are round about you; live around you”.

Deuteronomy 32:39 “See now that I am He, and there is none besides me” or “there is no god with me”.

1 Kings 8:60 “HaShem is G-d, [there is] none else.”

2 Kings 19:19 “that all the kingdoms of the earth may know that you HaShem, G-d, is the only one” or “that you alone HaShem art G-d”, “thy alone art HaShem G-d”.

1 Samuel 2:2 “None like HaShem” and “None besides Him”.

Psalm 81:9 “there shall not be strange gods among you” or “there shall not be a strange god in you [i.e. in your heart and mind]”.

Psalm 83:18

Isaiah 42:8 “I am HaShem, that is My name, I will not share/give My glory/honour to another”.

Isaiah 43:10 “So that ye know and give credence to Me [believe it], and understand that I am He, Before Me there was no god formed, And after Me there is none”. Isaiah 43:11 “besides Me there is no savior” - Hos 13:4.

Isaiah 44:6 “I am the first and the last, there is none god besides Me” - see also Isaiah 41:4 - Isaiah 44:8 “Is there any god besides Me? No god I know of!”

Isaiah 45:6 “I am HaShem, besides Me there is no other” or “and there is none else” - Isaiah 45:18, 22.

I can’t stress this enough, there is no other than G-d, only one G-d there is, and although He may present Himself to us in many ways or manners He will remain the same, always and ever.

The Tenach often refers to other gods as gods that were unknown, new gods, or elilim (weak, insignificant, nothing), false and strange, idols etc.  Why do you think this is so? These concepts of so called ‘other gods’ are in fact human creations, imaginations of the mind, existing forces or powers that are attributed by humans to self-conceived beings or turned into some being like an idol. But HaShem is clear there is none with Him, besides Him, in front of Him, underneath Him etc. from the beginning to the end, there only has been one G-d, HaShem is his name and He alone is G-d! *Hu Ha’Elohim*. And that’s why we proclaim the Shema in a way Rabbi Hirsch did: Understand Yisrael, HaShem your G-d, HaShem is (the Only) One (der Einige eine).”

Comment: I'm not too sure exactly what relevance you think these verses have. Christians of course uphold them just as much and strongly reject any idea that Jesus is "another God".

Comment: I'm not sure this is a relevant answer. The questioner asked whether there is such a view somewhere within Judaism. Can you vouch for all Jewish texts not containing anything of the sort that *may be* interpreted by *some* as a triune concept?

Comment: @curiousdannii I get you’re point but the original question is somewhat changed, but part of the question is still if such a triune belief is held by Jews. I just showed why we prefer to talk about Oneness based upon these verses.

Comment: @Harel13 see comment of RandomUser: “If the Trinity is not found in the Tanakh then it should be easily proven.” I was just showing some verses which shows why we believe in Oneness.

Comment: @Levi prior to his comment it was not clear from his question that he wanted sources specifically from the Tanach...

Answer (score 1):

No. But Judaism heavily emphasizes the shema, “Hear, O Israel: the L-rd our G-d, the L-rd is one." (Deuteronomy 6:4–9).

The notion about a trinity is a Christian, pagan idea alien to traditional Judaism. While some Christin ideas have tragically crept into Judaism over the years, the trinity is not one of them.

Comment: @Lucian I would like to refer to my answer and if you are a christian i would like to point out for you Mark 12 in which Jesus recites the Shema, on which a man reacts by saying this is true because there is only one G-d and no other besides Him. Jesus on his turn finds this to be the wise answer! But anyway, if you believe in G-d you should at least consider what He’s saying about Himself.

Comment: @Levi: The only Christian elements of my answer are mentioning that John's Gospel uses some of the same Platonic elements as Philo of Alexandria, and a small artwork illustrating Abraham's hospitality.

Comment: @Lucian No, I won't downvote your answer. I appreciate the comments. Tho I do not know why you decided to down-vote my answer.

Comment: @TurkHill: Because, as I hinted in my previous comment, on this particular post, the reverse of otherwise normal site rules apply; thus, if something is *pertinent*, it is to be *downvoted*, and if it is not, it is meant to be upvoted. :-)

Comment: @Lucian seems to be the case most of the time (but of course not all).